# How to send image as attachement without saving it in file system?

Tags: asp.net

I have one aspx page which content :

Code:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/JD.jpg" />
```

OR

```
<img ID="Image2" runat="server" alt="" src="~/Images/JD.jpg" />
```

I have to send this image as attachement in mail without saving in file system?

Actallay i have to send bug report in mail...It's like that user taking screen shot and send to admin...

Please suggest me..

Comment: but its already saved at `~/Images/JD.jpg`? Are you trying to use a `asp:FileUpload` instead?

Comment: It's already on the file system if you are pointing to that path, why not just take it from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for reference only.
[Sending Email with attachment in ASP.NET using SMTP Server](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/SivaEMailSample.aspx)

```
/* Beginning of Attachment1 process   & 
   Check the first open file dialog for a attachment */
if (inpAttachment1.PostedFile != null)
{
/* Get a reference to PostedFile object */
HttpPostedFile attFile = inpAttachment1.PostedFile;
 /* Get size of the file */
 int attachFileLength = attFile.ContentLength; 
 /* Make sure the size of the file is > 0  */
 if (attachFileLength > 0)
 {
 /* Get the file name */
 strFileName = Path.GetFileName(inpAttachment1.PostedFile.FileName);
 /* Save the file on the server */      
 inpAttachment1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));  
 /* Create the email attachment with the uploaded file */
 MailAttachment attach = new MailAttachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
 /* Attach the newly created email attachment */      
 mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attach);
 /* Store the attach filename so we can delete it later */
 attach1 = strFileName;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Actually i am taking my screenshot of my webpage and send it as image in mail.There is no physical location of this screen shot image. Please tell me how i will do?  Thanks

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek: After taking screenshot of webpage you have to save it and then using FileUpload control attach  it with mail message.

Comment: @Thomas , Actually i am working on flex and asp.net application.When i click on some button ,pop will come with preivous screen, details. Now i have to send this image and details in mail.

Comment: @Pankaj Pareek: I don't know much about the Flex. But if you are not able to click then you can use keyboard's keys to save it and then upload it using keys.