# Sending an attachment that the user chose with mail

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, attachment

**The problem**:

I want that users can send me mails with attachments. They can choose the file with an input file button in html. The problem is that it can't find the file. It works fine without attachments.

I get this error

> File C: Program Files (x 86) ExpressGIPENGLISH .pptx IIS cannot be found.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**What I tried**:

Tried first uploading the file to  that location but still doesn't work.

Input file button

```
<INPUT type=file id=File1 name=File1 runat="server" >&nbsp; </asp:Content>
```

C# Code

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File1.PostedFile.FileName));

MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("d***t@gmail.com", "d***t@gmail.com");

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.Port = 587;              
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("d***t@gmail.com", "");

mail.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
mail.Subject = TxtOnderwerp.Text;
mail.Body = TxtMail.Text;
mail.Body += Environment.NewLine + "Van  " + TxtNaam.Text;
mail.Body += Environment.NewLine + " Deze persoon is te bereiken op het mail adres " + TxtEmail.Text + " of op het nummer " + TxtTel.Text;
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

client.Send(mail);
```

**Result**: I want that a user can send me a mail with an attachment that he chose himself that is on his computer. And that I can receive the mail and open the attachment. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Below a complete example to add files to an email message as attachment without writing them to the disk.

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
{
    client.Host = "host.com";
    client.Port = 25;
    client.Timeout = 10000;
    client.EnableSsl = false;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");

    message.From = new MailAddress("email@from.nl", "VDWWD");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("email@to.nl"));
    message.Subject = "Your uploaded files";
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Body = "<html><head></head><body><font face=\"arial\" size=\"2\"><b>The files you uploaded.</b></font></body></html>";

    //loop all the uploaded files
    foreach (var file in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
    {
        //add the file from the fileupload as an attachment
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(file.InputStream, file.FileName, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet));
    }

    //send mail
    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the posted file to your server before you can add it as an attachment. You can also add the attachment from a MemoryStream, so this could be another way without having to save the file itself.

Comment: *You will need to save the posted file to your server before you can add it as an attachment. You can also add the attachment from a MemoryStream, so this could be another way without having to save the file itself.* **... or the simplest way: use `HttpPostedFile.InputStream` directly to create `Attachment` ...** no saving, no unnecessary MemoryStream

Comment: @Selvin do u  some more info about that or an example? I looked it up and it's verry complicated for me. Started programming only a few months ago .Thank you in advance

Comment: No, as @Selvin says you do not need to store it on the server first to add it as an attachment.